# how to save a pdf page into mp3 from gTTS

Tags: python, tkinter, operating-system, gtts

```
def play():
    global text_2
    global language
    #print(text_2)
    my_audio = gTTS(text=text_2, lang=language)
    my_audio.save("hello.mp3")
```

here text_2 is a page from pdf

when  I run this I get an error
but when I run this with short text it works perfectly fine .

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python3.9\lib\threading.py", line 950, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\python3.9\lib\threading.py", line 888, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\NK Infosystem\PycharmProjects\audiobook\main.py", line 79, in play
    my_audio.save("hello.mp3")
  File "C:\python3.9\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 311, in save
    self.write_to_fp(f)
  File "C:\python3.9\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 293, in write_to_fp
    raise gTTSError(tts=self, response=r)
gtts.tts.gTTSError: 200 (OK) from TTS API. Probable cause: Unknown
```

Comment: There may be issue on connecting to Google Translate service.

Comment: but it is working when I put small text to  convert